# Resample timeseries in chunks from large CSV without splitting intervals

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I'm reading a large CSV with a timeseries. I have values every second and want to resample that e.g. to maximum and averages of 15 minute intervals. I use pandas.read_csv() with chunks. Now the problem is, that the chunk might end in the middle of a 15 minute interval, so if I run it the first chunk might end on an interval at e.g. 12:00:00 and the second chunk might start with an intervall at 12:00:00.

What would be the quick solution to split the DataFrame from the first chunk at the last 15 minute interval and take that data over to the next chunk?

```
import pandas as pd

source_file = './timeseries.csv'
chunksize = 10 ** 6

for chunk in pd.read_csv(
        source_file, 
        chunksize=chunksize, 
        delimiter=';',
        decimal=',',
        na_values='.',
        index_col=0, 
        parse_dates=[0,]):

    closed_15min_chunk = ???

    usable_chunk = pd.concat([buffered_chunk, closed15_min_chunk])

    buffered_chunk = ???

    avg_chunk = usable_chunk.resample('15min').mean().round(2)
    max_chunk = usable_chunk.resample('15min').max().round(2)

    print(avg_chunk)
```

Comment: Your timestamps are continuous or do they last say from 09:00 in the morning until 17:00 and then restart on a different day?

Comment: @JoaoPedroMacalos They might have gaps. I usually have an entry every second, but there might be gaps of any size, from a couple of seconds to a cople of days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think have found an answer! Feel free to post a better answer. In the example below, I only use the average chunk for better readability.

```
import pandas as pd

source_file = './timeseries.csv'
chunksize = 10 ** 6

buffer_chunk = None

for chunk in pd.read_csv(
        source_file, 
        chunksize=chunksize, 
        delimiter=';',
        decimal=',',
        na_values='.',
        index_col=0, 
        parse_dates=[0,]):

    if buffer_chunk is not None:
        print(f"Loaded Chunk start: {chunk.iloc[0].name}")
        chunk = pd.concat([buffer_chunk, chunk])
        print(f"Buffered chunk: {buffer_chunk.iloc[0].name} - {buffer_chunk.iloc[-1].name}")
        print(f"Chunk: {chunk.iloc[0].name} - {chunk.iloc[-1].name}")

    avg_chunk = chunk.resample('15min').mean().round(2)
    print(f"Last resampled {avg_chunk.iloc[-1].name}")

    idx = 1
    while chunk.iloc[-idx].name > avg_chunk.iloc[-1].name:
        idx += 1
    print(f"Cutoff: {chunk.iloc[-idx].name}")
    avg_chunk.drop(index=avg_chunk.index[-1], 
                   axis=0, 
                   inplace=True)
    print(f"Last resampled {avg_chunk.iloc[-1].name}")
    buffer_chunk = chunk.iloc[-idx:]
```